# Как кастомизировать background в view controller?

Tags: xcode, swift

Мне нужно сделать вот такой background во всех своих вью контроллерах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При работе с андроидом я собирал такой xml файл

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:thickness="0dp">

<gradient
    android:angle="180"
    android:endColor="@color/ntz_background_grey"
    android:centerColor="@color/ntz_background_light_grey"
    android:startColor="@color/ntz_background_grey"
    android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

В котором и описывал кастомизацию , какой цвет вначале, какой с середине и в конце и получался вот такой бекграунд.

Как сделать такое в Xcode ? Я нашел только несколько ответов где объяснялось как поставить картинку на бекграунд, но мне кажется, что должен быть способ кастомизации.

Или как это работает в Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну в общем-то все сводится к картинке на бэкграунд. Но можно в коде сделать все что нам угодно, сначала градиент, а затем поставить его как цвет фона. Один из вариантов:

```
func createGradientBackground() {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.darkGray.cgColor, UIColor.lightGray.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
    gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image!)
}
```

ну и результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]